# How many typos?

Tags: code-golf, error-correction

A typo is said to have occurred if:

- A character is missing.
- A character is extra.
- A character is replaced with another wrong character.

For the purpose of this challenge, only lowercase characters and spaces are used.

Input will be a dictionary of words, followed by one line of input. You need to find the (minimum) number of typos in it.

**Sample data**

For all testcases, I've assumed the dictionary to be:

```
heart
hearth
heard
heaves
aves
he
art
ear
```

Input 1

```
heart heard
```

Output 1

```
0
```

Input 2

```
he art
```

Output 2

```
0
```

Input 3

```
kill us
```

Output 3

```
6
```

(1 to delete the space, and 5 more to change the word to hearth)

Input 4

```
heave art
```

Output 4

```
1
```

Input 5

```
earth artear
```

Output 5

```
2
```

**Shortest code wins.**

Please let me know of any other ambiguous testcases. I will add them here as well.

P.S.

Someone flagged this as a duplicate of [Find the minimum edit distance between two strings](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/5174/find-the-minimum-edit-distance-between-two-strings)

It is not a duplicate, in fact, my challenge is *much* harder. The main reasons being that:

- Substitutions are counted only as one typo in my Q, not two.
- The space is also counted as a character, and at the same time behaves like a word-separator.

Comment: Can you provide a list of english words?

Comment: Because I know I can use `/usr/share/dict/words` but that file is like, a megabyte

Comment: @flawr Please see my clarification on why this is not a dup.

Comment: Scoring a substitution as 1 vs 2 involves literally no more than changing a single character from 1 to 2 in some (most?) of the answers to the older question, so I have no idea why you think that makes it "***much** harder*". I'm not sure I understand what you mean with the other reason.